# Isospin conservation for total isospin or third component of isospin?

Tags: particle-physics, strong-force, isospin-symmetry

In a strong interaction, is the total isospin or just its third component conserved? Or are they both conserved?

Answer (score 8):

The third component of isospin is isomorphic to electric charge, which is (so far as we know) an *exact* symmetry in all systems.

The total isospin is an *approximate* symmetry of the strong nuclear interaction.

Comment: Weak $W^{+/-}$ flips isospin, right? Anywho, OP's question is restricted to strong interaction.

Comment: Weak interactions like $e\to W\nu$ follow more or less the same isospin-conservation rules as strong interactions like $p\to\pi n$ --- even though weak isospin and strong isospin are not quite the same thing.

Comment: could one come up with an example where total isospin is not conserved in the weak interaction？

Comment: @JinH Strong isospin is changed by $∆I=1/2$ in $s\to d$ decays, and by $∆I=1$ in $\pi\to\mu$ decays. If you mean weak isospin, please ask a follow up question; link it here so I'll be sure to notice it.

Comment: @rob thanks, I somehow confused myself, so the isospin of up and down quarks is a completely different quantum number as the isospin of leptons. And of course there are mixing defined by the CKM matrix.

Comment: @JinH Yes. The [Wikipedia article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isospin) (currently) has a very nice discussion.

Answer (score -1):

They are both conserved. Strong interactions conserves all quantum numbers. Electromagnetic interactions doesn't conserve total isospin I, but conserves the third component I3. See [image: this useful summary table] from an exercise book

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "Strong interactions conserves all quantum numbers." For example, it doesn't conserve the sum of the intrinsic spins. Please say what book this is from. Cutting and pasting stuff  on the internet without attribution is rude.