# Is isospin magnitude $I$ conserved?

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, strong-force, isospin-symmetry

Here is a table of isospin conservation in certain reactions.

It is often loosely stated that 'isospin is always conserved in strong interactions', but it is never clear whether they mean total isospin I or its component I3. Also in the table below for the middle reaction it appears that sometimes a superposition of I=0,1 can react into just I=1, suggesting I may not be conserved.

In this question isospin conservation for total isospin or third component of isospin? it confirms that I3 is conserved but just says 'I is an approximate symmetry', not being clear to whether that means I itself is conserved or not while another answer says it is conserved but is downvoted.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [isospin conservation for total isospin or third component of isospin?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/431219/)

Comment: [Linked](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/69582/does-strong-interaction-care-about-mass-isospin-question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table is invisible, but I'll answer by explaining the "why", from which all else follows.

If you switched off all interactions, and set the masses of the up and down quarks equal, you'd have a perfect *su(2)* symmetry of your Hamiltonian, so 3 generators conserved, and hence both the Casimir and the $I_3$ generator conserved. But this is not a fact of nature, as $m_d=4.8MeV \approx 2\times m_u$, where $m_u=2.3MeV$, so, quite badly broken.

How does coupling to the strong interactions make it an approximate, pretty good, symmetry? Unlike electromagnetism and the weak interactions, the strong interactions couple "blindly" to the up and down quarks, and so  treat them both equally. The strong force  breaks chiral symmetry dynamically and converts the above current quark masses to  constituent quark masses, both about 300MeV, a third of the nucleon mass,  as the strong interactions are characterized by a much higher scale, $\Lambda_{QCD}\approx 200MeV$, w.r.t. which the above mass difference is insignificant, $\kappa = (m_d-m_u)/\Lambda_{QCD}\approx$ 1%.

So the strong interactions do their thing and they barely notice the 1% isospin breaking. Within such small breaking slop, Isospin and G-parity, predicated on it, are excellent approximate symmetries. This means that Isospin, all 3 generators, and hence their Casimir, I(I+1), are essentially conserved in the strong interactions. You use this conservation in all Clebsching problems in all reactions, as elementary particle texts instruct you to, with lots of problems relying on it.

$I_3$ is actually better protected against the explicit breaking of the other two generators, because it does not change quark flavor, so it just counts the up and down content difference of your process, and depends less on masses.

Adding the strange quark, whose mass is very different, has trained people to systematically account for this flavor *su(3)* breaking, the technology of the celebrated Eightfold Way: there is beautiful method in its madness.

When you switch on the electromagnetic and weak interactions, isospin is broken by subleading corrections, comparable or bigger to the mass breaking, *κ*, above, and you need sensible perturbative ways to account for it.

But the takeaway is that *the entire isospin su(2) is conserved in the strong interactions, and you should utilize its conservation  the way you would spin*.

In the context of your specific question with the  emergent table,
because of isospin conservation, you *know* that *only* the isotriplet combination of your reactants goes to the uniquely isotriplet final state, and the isosinglet combination channel  does not connect to the reaction!

Comment: Thank you this was helpful, I've added the table now. Could you just explain why the isospin magnitude goes from 0 or 1 to just 1 in the above reaction too?

Comment: No, it does *not* go from I=0 to I=1 ! This channel is closed. By conservation of isospin, only the I=1 channel of the reactants is selected, to go to the I=1 state of the products. The deuteron, of course, is an [isosinglet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deuterium#Approximated_wavefunction_of_the_deuteron).

Comment: But the sum of the neutron and positron isospin could either have I=0 or I=1, and thus their state is a superposition of both as shown in the table?

Comment: Unless that state in the table is incorrect, and instead a density matrix should be used with pure I=0 OR I=1 states (instead of a superposition)?

Comment: How do you mean "but"? The isosinglet combination in the superposition does *not* overlap with the products. It does *not* decay to them. Only the isotriplet, I=1, does.  Think of the decay as a "measurement".

Comment: Oh so you're considering the different constitutent states in the superposition separately. Why is that? So are you saying that the consistent I's in a wavefunction are not conserved (and so the expectation of I is not conserved), but just that its conserved in the sense that 'if you measure some I value, at least one of the constituent states in the inital wavefunction superposition must have had that I value'. Is that correct?

Comment: Of course: haven't you done any spin problems?Isospin conservation works no differently than angular momentum conservation. It is isospin conservation that leads you to the decay going through solely the isovector channel.

Comment: Ah that makes alot of sense now thanks, this has been taught very poorly to me.